# Is there any way to customize OpenSSL source code

Tags: c, linux, encryption, openssl

I have downloaded OpenSSL source code and installed from it. I have gone through the aes.h header file and there is one function AES_encrypt which is declared in aes.h , but defined inside aes_core.c . Now I want to check when AES_encrypt executed inside my C program , whether the AES_encrypt function is called or not? For that purpose I add a print statement inside AES_encrypt function, then install OpenSSL from the modified source files. But when I am executing my program I am not getting the customized messages of AES_encrypt function.

Here is what I made changes inside aes_core.c ( /crypto/aes/aes_core.c)

```
void AES_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
         const AES_KEY *key) {

    printf( " I am inside aes_core.c \n"); // added by me
```

I have added same message in every files wherever AES_encrypt () function is defined. To my surprise not  a single message is printed inside AES_encrypt (  I have written inside 2-3 files wherever this function is defined).

Before AES_encrypt () is called in my C program , I called the AES_set_encrypt_key() .

definition of

```
AES_set_encrypt_key() 
{
  printf(I am here inside aes_misc.c);// added by me
  return (private_AES_set_encrypt_key()) ; // This invokes private_AES_set_encrypt_key() in other C program
}
```

To my surprise I only get message for AES_set_encrypt_key which is declared inside aes_misc.c ( this indirectly invokes another function ( return **private_AES_set_encrypt_key()** ) but the message in that private_AES_set_encrypt_key function is not printed.

Here is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "openssl/aes.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  AES_KEY aesKey_;
  unsigned char userKey_[16];
  unsigned char in_[16];
  unsigned char out_[16];
  strcpy((char *)userKey_,"0123456789123456");
  strcpy((char *)in_,"0123456789123456");

  //while(1)
  {
    fprintf(stdout,"Original message: %s\n", in_);
    AES_set_encrypt_key(userKey_, 128, &aesKey_);
    AES_encrypt(in_, out_, &aesKey_);

    AES_set_decrypt_key(userKey_, 128, &aesKey_);
    AES_decrypt(out_, in_,&aesKey_);
    fprintf(stdout,"Recovered Original message: %s\n", in_);      
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Original message: 0123456789123456
I am here inside aes_misc.c 
Recovered Original message: 0123456789123456
```

Why this is happening ? How other function is called ? What is the flow of the program execution ? I am using GCC under Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -g -O` and use the `gdb` debugger. Read [Drepper's paper: how to write shared libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Comment: I'm slightly baffled why you try to do this? If you just want to debug OpenSSL, there are plenty of ways to do that as pointed above (use gdb at least before poking with the library code as it's most likely not the source of your problem, whatever that might be).

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL is not using the code inside aes_core.c unless you explicitely ask for it by using the 'no-asm' option at configure time. You may have seen the

```
#ifndef AES_ASM
```

at the beginning of aes_core.c.

The real AES functions are using architecture-specific code, located in crypto/aes/asm/. Depending your architecture and whether or not your CPU has the AES-NI instructions set, you may have to look at crypto/aes/asm/aes-x86_64.pl, crypto/aes/asm/aesni-x86_64.pl or whatever.

Comment: thanks for answering. I have checked in my system , AES-NI is not supported, only AES supported.

Comment: I also have seen the source code of crypto/aes/asm/aes-x86_64.pl and there is another AES_encrypt function exist. Does this function called ?

Comment: If you are using a x86_64 (aka amd64) processor without AES-NI support, yes, that's very probable.